# A C++ text editing component that handles footnotes?

Tags: c++, components, editing, footnotes

After a cursory glance round and some thinking, the only way I can think of to create a footnoting editing component is several rich edit controls, though with this method there's many caveats.

Does anyone know of any existing component which handles anything like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a MS Word window using OLE.

Failing that you might need to "roll your own".